# Не происходит вставка в таблицу

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Есть таблица:

```
user_id | target | shool | created_at | updated_at
```

Пытаюсь вставить запись, но не вставляется:

```
$shooladd = UserSubject::create(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'target' => $request->targets, 'shool' => $request->shools]);
        if ($shooladd) dd($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          $shooladd = new UserSubject;
            $shooladd ->user_id= Auth::user()->id;
            $shooladd ->target= $request->targets;
            $shooladd ->shool= $request->shools;
            $shooladd ->save();
   if ($shooladd) dd($request->all());
```

попробуй добавить так

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83070/discussion-on-answer-by-aram77778-----).